# Access with links to SharePoint crashes

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, hyperlink

I have an Access 2013 DB with links to SharePoint 2013 which I have created multiple times. Each time I create it, I can do anything I want with the DB and the linked lists, until I close the Access DB. Once the database has been closed, the next time it opens and a linked list is accessed, it just clocks; no password prompt, nothing.

I think it has something to do with credentials but I am never prompted to authenticate with SharePoint when I attempt to open any link.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what causes this problem seems to have something to do with 64bit O/S or office 64bit, I've seen it in 2010 as well. I tried running different custom functions to alter the database options via vba, all with limited success.

I ended up creating an AutoExec macro that runs the equivalent to DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdRefreshSharePointList)

go to Create tab > then select Macro under 'Macros & Code'>

then add the 'RunMenuCommand' action, 
and set the 'command to run' to 'RefreshSharepointList'.

and upon saving the macro, ensure it is called "AutoExec" and nothing else.

Let me know if this worked for you.

**Update:**

I've been getting occasional errors when using the above method, if it works for you, great, if not, try this.

insert the following function into a module, replace "table1" with any linked sharepoint table in your db:

```
Function refreshList()
CurrentDb.TableDefs("table1").RefreshLink
End Function
```

Using the same procedure as above, insert the 'RunCode' macro step instead of the 'RunMenuCommand' and in the space enter 'refreshList()', this should invoke the login prompt correctly. Note: just remember to make sure you don't have a form that uses sharepoint data opening up when the database opens by default.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem as well, and I found my solution through this article:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2905177

I'm using Method 1 to resolve my issue, which is as stated in the link:

> **Method 1: Refresh List**
>
> 1. Open Windows Task Manager, select Microsoft Access and click **End task**
> 2. Reopen the database.
> 3. Right-click on the linked table in Access, choose
>      **More Options -> Refresh List**
> 4. Log in with your credentials

For Method 2, you can follow the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20931235/19582) above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem with SharPoint 2013 lists in an Access database in Access 2010. 2013 and 2016 and the refresh method definitely helps.

Clearly this is a long-known bug that Microsoft (KB2905177 is from 2013) and Microsoft won't be doing anything about it. I think Access is in low maintenance mode and the only updates will be ones which help you to move off it.